# difference between np.inf and float('Inf')

Tags: python, numpy

Is there some difference between NumPy `np.inf` and `float('Inf')`?
`float('Inf') == np.inf` returns `True`, so it seems they are interchangeable, thus I was wondering why NumPy has defined its own "inf" constant, and when should I use one constant instead of the other (considering style concerns too)?

Comment: I think it is because Numpy redifined is own variable in c in order to perform operation faster (using Cython) http://notes-on-cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/std_dev.html

Comment: @MaxChrétien What you mean are the constants in [`npy_math`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html#numpy-core-math-library), especially [`NPY_INFINITY`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html#c.NPY_INFINITY).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### TL, DR: There is no difference and they can be used interchangeably.

Besides having the same value as `math.inf` and `float('inf')`:

```
>>> import math
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.inf == float('inf')
True
>>> np.inf == math.inf
True
```

It also has the same type:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> type(np.inf)
float
>>> type(np.inf) is type(float('inf'))
float
```

That's interesting because NumPy also has it's own floating point types:

```
>>> np.float32(np.inf)
inf
>>> type(np.float32(np.inf))
numpy.float32
>>> np.float32('inf') == np.inf  # nevertheless equal
True
```

So it has the same value and the same type as `math.inf` and `float('inf')` which means it's interchangeable.

### Reasons for using `np.inf`

1. It's less to type:

- `np.inf` (6 chars)
- [`math.inf`](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.inf) (8 chars; new in python 3.5)
- `float('inf')` (12 chars)

That means if you already have NumPy imported you can save yourself 6 (or 2) chars per occurrence compared to `float('inf')` (or `math.inf`).

2. Because it's easier to remember.

At least for me, it's far easier to remember `np.inf` than that I need to call `float` with a string.

Also, NumPy defines some additional aliases for infinity:

```
    np.Inf
    np.inf
    np.infty
    np.Infinity
    np.PINF
```

It also defines an alias for negative infinity:

```
    np.NINF
```

Similarly for `nan`:

```
    np.nan
    np.NaN
    np.NAN
```

3. Constants are constants

This point is based on CPython and could be completely different in another Python implementation.

A `float` CPython instance requires 24 Bytes:

```
    >>> import sys
    >>> sys.getsizeof(np.inf)
    24
```

If you can re-use the same instance you might save a lot of memory compared to creating lots of new instances. Of course, this point is mute if you create your own `inf` constant but if you don't then:

```
    a = [np.inf for _ in range(1000000)]
    b = [float('inf') for _ in range(1000000)]
```

`b` would use 24 * 1000000 Bytes (~23 MB) more memory than `a`.

4. Accessing a constant is faster than creating the variable.

   ```
    %timeit np.inf
    37.9 ns ± 0.692 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
    %timeit float('inf')
    232 ns ± 13.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

    %timeit [np.inf for _ in range(10000)]
    552 µs ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
    %timeit [float('inf') for _ in range(10000)]
    2.59 ms ± 78.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
   ```

Of course, you can create your own constant to counter that point. But why bother if NumPy already did that for you.

Comment: np.inf == float('inf') -> True

Comment: There's another reason not to use `Float('Inf')`: `Float('Inf') is Float('Inf')` returns `False`, while both `math.inf is math.inf` and `np.inf is np.inf` return `True`.

Comment: @berna1111 True, but one should never actually compare numbers using `ìs`. `is` is for reference equality **not** for value equality. If you need to compare numbers (except `nan`, there you have to use an `isnan` function) always use `==`, never `is`.

Comment: I wasn't clear with the intent of the `is` usage, I meant that `np.inf` and `math.if` appear to work as singletons, probably using less memory when a lot of them are used. There are [`np.isinf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) and [`np.isfinite`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) methods, that should probably be used if one expects those kind of values. But that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @berna1111 I thought I covered that in point 3 (memory) and 4 (faster access time) of my answer.

Comment: @berna1111 Yes, there is `np.isinf` and `np.isfinite` but sometimes it really makes sense to use explicit `x == np.inf` comparisons. Especially if you care about the sign of the infinity.

Comment: This first argument comparing the lengths of the different "inf" representations is not exactly fair, since numpy is imported as `np`. You could also `import math as m` and use `m.inf` (although I am not necessarily recommending this).

Comment: @n1000 At the time I wrote the answer Python 3.5 wasn't that common (so `math.inf` simply wasn't available to almost everyone) so the comparison was more aimed at the `float('inf')` (and more oriented at the usual import names). However since one can easily create the constant themselves the point is actually mute. It depends mostly on which package you already have imported, because an additional import just to use `inf` would be a bit pointless. But thank you for bringing this up.